# update table in sql not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am tring to update data of private_tutor Table. But its not working .
But when I write the sql command

```
(UPDATE private_tutor SET name='private' , contact_number='0000' , 
                          address='dw', experience='s', 
                          qualification='dwd' , age='dwd', about='dwd'
                          WHERE id=1)
```

in terminal it updates , table.

What may be the reason , I am giving the same query through php. why its not working ?

output

```
UPDATE private_tutor SET name='private' , contact_number='0000' , address='dw', experience='s', qualification='dwd' , age='dwd', about='dwd' WHERE id=1
There is some problem in adding record
```

update.php

```
<?php     //start php tag
//include connect.php page for database connection
include('connect.php');

include('session.php');

//if submit is not blanked i.e. it is clicked.
Echo $_GET['profile-name'].$_GET['profile-contact'].$_GET['address'].$_GET['experience'].$_GET['qualification'].$_GET['age'].$_GET['about'].$_GET['id'];

If(isset($_GET['submit']))
{

    $sql="UPDATE private_tutor 
             SET name='".$_GET['profile-name']."' , 
                contact_number='".$_GET['profile-contact']."' ,  
                address='".$_GET['address']."', 
                experience='".$_GET['experience']."', 
                qualification='".$_GET['qualification']."' , 
                age='".$_GET['age']."', 
                about='".$_GET['about']."' 
             WHERE  id=".$_GET['id']." ";

echo "</br>".$sql."</br>";

$res=$conn->query($sql);
If($res)
{
        header('Location:private-tutor-profile.php');   
}
Else
{
Echo "There is some problem in adding record";
}


}

?>
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. This `Echo "There is some problem in adding record";` does not help you. Use `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: You are getting all those data through URL?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Note that it is VERY DANGEROUS to perform database writes in PHP that is called by HTTP GET.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul What is he has a `method="GET"` in his `<form>` tag. Dont assume, ask for clarification!

Comment: Are you using PDO or `mysql_` as the database connection mechanism?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Also it is **no more difficult to fake** a POST that it is a GET.

Comment: @RiggsFolly oops, almost forgot that thing. I don't remember when's the last time I used `method="GET"`. I should delete my comment, otherwise it would confuse OP even further.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of outputting your own error message which tells you next to nothing about the problem, output the error message from the database connection.

So instead of this line

```
Echo "There is some problem in adding record";
```

Do this instead:

If `$conn` is `PDO`

```
echo print_r( $conn->error_info );
```

If `$conn` is `MYSQLI_`

```
echo $conn->error;
```

But quite possibly, your connection has failed and you do not show us that code!! And I assume you are not looking for error messages there either.